# How to change the shape of an numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a variable `p` of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

The value of `p.shape` is `(100, 1)`.

How can I convert it to `(100,)`?

The content of `p` is

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       ...
       [98],
       [99],
       [100]])
```

I want to convert it to

```
array( [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       ...
       [98],
       [99],
       [100])
```

Comment: The "I want to convert it to" output isn't a valid array, which raises the questions of why you want to perform this conversion and whether it's really what you need.

Comment: try `p.flatten()`?

Comment: `p.reshape(100)` will do it